# Laravel7 2 Table joining with complex data

Tags: laravel-7

I want to show the data from tbl_structure with people name from tble_peple but I don't know how to join it. I am a new on laravel.

[my tbl_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F56U7.png)

[my tble_peple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhLuR.png)

[showing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0xIu.png)

my code on Controller

```
public function get_people(){
 $Showstructe= DB::table('tbl_structure')->orderby("name","asc")
 ->get();
 return view('admin.TestCustomer.structure_show',compact('Showstructe'));
}
```

my code to show data

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
 <tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Structure</th>
  <th>Stage A</th>
  <th>Stage B</th>
  <th>Stage C</th>
  <th>Stage D</th>
  <th>Stage E</th>
  <th>Stage F</th>
</tr>
@foreach($Showstructe as $people)
<tr>
  <td>{{ $people->id }}</td>
  <td>{{ $people->name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $people->stage_a }}</td>
  <td>{{ $people->stage_b }}</td>
  <td>{{ $people->stage_c }}</td>
  <td>{{ $people->stage_d }}</td>
  <td>{{ $people->stage_e }}</td>
  <td>{{ $people->stage_f }}</td>
<tr>
@endforeach
</table>
```

How to show people name not just people id?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function get_people(){
     $Showstructe= DB::table('tbl_structure')->leftJoin('people as p', 'tbl_structure.id', '=', 'p.id')->select('p.name as peopleName')->orderby("name","asc")
     ->get();
     return view('admin.TestCustomer.structure_show',compact('Showstructe'));
    }


<table class="table table-bordered">
 <tr>
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Structure</th>
  <th>Stage A</th>
  <th>Stage B</th>
  <th>Stage C</th>
  <th>Stage D</th>
  <th>Stage E</th>
  <th>Stage F</th>
</tr>
@foreach($Showstructe as $people)
<tr>
  <td>{{ $people->peopleName}}</td>
  <td>{{ $people->name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $people->stage_a }}</td>
  <td>{{ $people->stage_b }}</td>
  <td>{{ $people->stage_c }}</td>
  <td>{{ $people->stage_d }}</td>
  <td>{{ $people->stage_e }}</td>
  <td>{{ $people->stage_f }}</td>
<tr>
@endforeach
</table>
```